# How does an object use a method of another object?

Tags: java, object, message

I have, for example, a `class Doctor` who wants to use the services of a `class Postman`.

How does it look like in terms of code?

```
public class Doctor
{
    ...

    void doCheckup(Patient);
    void sendMail(){   // want to use services of a Postman here }
}

public class Postman
{
    void sendMail(...){ ... }
}
```

I might define `Doctor::sendMail()` as

```
void sendMail()
{
    Postman A = new Postman();
    A.sendMail(...);
}
```

Is that correct?

If it is, then why should a 'Doctor' create a 'Postman'? It sounds really far away from real life scenarios. Is that how messages are shared between objects?

Comment: That's one way...  Another is with static methods, then instead of instantiating a new Postman, you do `Postman.SendMail("Hello world!");`.  My question to you is: Have you read up on the basics of object-oriented programming?  All tutorials explain (sometimes in excruciating detail)

Comment: Inside doctor make 1 instance of Postman, then inside Doctor you send messages to that Postman instance. You don't need to create a new Postman instance every time you want to use one of it's methods. If they are just utility methods make them static.

Comment: If anyone can send mail, you may create a class `Human` with method `sendMail()` and make `Doctor` and `Postman` herit from it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make a "real world model" of things, then you would have a global PostOffice object, which would contain many Postmen.

The Doctor could be part of a DoctorOffice, or a Hospital

The Doctor would have a member variable pointing to HIS Postman

```
Doctor.Postman = aPostmanObject;
```

He would then let the postman do the work.

```
Doctor.Postman.SendMail();
```

Assuming you made "SendMail" a public method of Postman (which it would be, as he is doing this as a public service)

Answer (score 2):

A more idiomatic way would be to have something like:

```
void sendMail(Postman postman) {
   postman.sendMail(...);
```

Don't create the other object inside the first one.

On a sidenote, `Doctor::sendMail` is C++ syntax. In Java, there is no `::`